# Who is that Bhuvaneshwari devi as mentioned in Srimad Devi Bhagavatam?

Tags: puranas, devi, shakti, shaktism, devi-bhagavata-purana

As all shaktas know that the Deity of Devi Bhagavatam is Adya shakti Bhuvaneshwari. But there are some confusions though.

In devi bhagvatam devi Bhuvaneshwari is called as Moolprakriti from whom 5 devis appeared named- Durga,Radha,Lakshmi,Saraswati and Savitri. So,my doubt is that among Mahavidyas the fourth Mahavidya is known as Bhuvaneshwari. But here in devi bhagvatam she is called as Moolprakriti from whom every shakti appeared. She is Adya. And we all know the fourth name of Mahavidya. So if Bhuvaneshwari is a Mahavidya then how could she be the Moolprakriti as Mahavidyas are forms of Devi DURGA alone.But according to devi bhagvatam Durga devi is main form of Mulaprakriti. Means Mulaprakriti Bhuvaneshwari manifest as Durga,Radha and so on....
And one more point is it is written there that all Mahavidyas serves Devi Bhuvaneshwari at Manidweepa. And her 10 stairs of her throne represents 10 Mahavidyas. If she is 4th mahavidyas then how could be her 10 stairs are 10 mahavidyas? It means that the Deity Bhuvaneshwari of Devi Bhagavatam is not same as MAHAVIDYA BHUVANESHWARI.

Then now please clear my doubts by solving these problems.

NOTE- Please I want answer only from the Shakta Perspective.

Comment: Please stop adding unnecessary salutations to your question.Your question will be more fine and readable as edited not in its original form, imo

Comment: Ok. I am here for my doubts. Not for usless debates. So.. thanks for your editz

Comment: What the hack. You removed my main line?? Damnn. So that means here also spiritual politics occur. We even can't ask our question freely.

Comment: Please do whatever you want to do. The MODS will handle this then. Edit it as per your own choice!

Answer (score 1):

There are Multiple expansions of Devi Bhuvanesvari shown living in Manidvipa alongside her, many of them going by the moniker of Bhuvanesvari. So the Bhuvanesvari among the 10 mahavidyas is her expansion.

### Devi Bhagavata Book 12 Chapter 11

> On the four sides there exist innumerable houses, tanks, reservoirs,
> all built of Navaratna; these belong to the Devīs, the presiding
> Deities of Āmnāyas (that which is to be studied or learnt by heart;
> the Vedas). The ten Mahā Vidyās, Kālī, Tārā, etc., of Śrī Devī and the
> Mahābhedās, that is, their all the Avatāras all dwell here with their
> respective Āvaraṇas, Vāhanas and ornaments. All the Avatāras of Śrī
> Devī for the killing of the Daityas and for showing favour to the
> devotees live here. They are Paśaṃkuśeśvarī, **Bhuvaneśvarī, Bhairavī,
> Kapāla Bhuvaneśvarī, Aṃkuśa Bhuvaneśvarī, Pramāda bhuvaneśvarī, Śrī
> Krodha Bhuvaneśvarī, Tripuṭāśvārūdhā, Nityaklinnā, Annapurnā, Tvaritā,
> and the other avatāras of Bhuvaneśvarī, and Kālī, Tārā and the other
> Mahāvidyās are known as Mahāvidyās.** They live here with their
> Āvaraṇa Devatās, Vāhanas, and ornaments respectively.

Now coming to the description of Srimata Bhuvanesvari of Devi Bhagavata who is the Mistress of Mani dvipa she is none other that the consort of Bhuvanesvara Maha Deva as described by the Devi Bhagavata itself.

### Devi Bhagavata, Book 12, Chapter 12

> O King! Now I shall describe about the main, Khās, room of Śrī Devī.
> Listen. The Khās Mahāl palace of the Devī Bhagavatī is named Śrī
> Cintāmaṇi Griha. Within this is placed the raised platform, the dais
> and sofa whereon the Devī taketh Her honourable seat. The ten
> Śakti-tattvas form the staircases. The four legs are (1) Brahmā, (2)
> Viṣṇu, (3) Rudra, and (4) Maheśvara. Sadāśiva forms the upper covering
> plank. **Over this Śrī Bhuvaneśvara Mahā Deva or the Supreme Architect
> of the Universe is reigning. Now hear something about this
> Bhuvaneśvara. Before creation while intending to sport, the Devī
> Bhagavatī divided Her Body into two parts and from the right part
> created Bhuvaneśvara. He has five faces and each face has three
> eyes.** He has four hands and He is holding in each hand speer, signs
> indicating do not fear, axe, and signs granting boons. He looks
> sixteen years old. The lustre of of His Body is more beautiful then
> Koṭi Kandarpas and more fiery than thousand Suns; and at the same time
> cool like Koṭi Suns. **His colour is crystal white, and on His left
> lap Śrī Bhuvaneśvarī Devī is always sitting.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's basically Maa Ambika Shivā, the consort of Bhagawan Shiva.

Skanda Purana : Devi Bhagawata Mahatmayam : Ch5: verse 96.:

> “Therefore of the Bhagavata which is dear to devi, even the great Puranas also aren’t entitled to even a part of the (greatness of the) **Purana of Shodashi”**.

Skanda Purana : Devi Bhagawata Mahatmayam : Ch5: verse 97.:

> “(In it is narrated) The secret meaning of Gayatri, and Manidweepa is described, in which exists the **Bhagavati Gita, Gita by Sridevi the daughter of himavan**”.

Skanda Purana : Devi Bhagawata Mahatmayam : Ch5: verse 101-102.:

> “At the end of the well of nectar in the garden of thirty three trees inside the Manidweepa, within the Chintamanigruha, **charmingly remains seated Amba with a smiling face in the heart (left portion) of Parashiva** – such an appearance when meditated by humans they get all types of enjoyments as well as liberation. One who is worshiped by Brahma, Rudra, Achyuta, Sakra and great sages, she is for the benefit of the world, the presiding lordess of the Manidweepa“.

So, though Srimad Devi Bhagwatam generally in the Purana talks about Mata Bhubaneswari, Sri Skanda Purana tells it as the Purana of Shodashi (Mata Maha Tripura Sundari).

Lalita Sahasranama Stotram 1:32.:

> “**Lalita – who out of her finger nails re-created all the ten Incarnations of Narayana (Vishnu)** to destroy the Asuras slain by Him in His incarnations and now recreated magically by demon-Bhanda out of a missile of his. She again burned to death the armies of demons with the fire of the great missile maha-pashupata”.

10 Avataras of Lord Vishnu = 10 Mahavidyas.

Mundamala Tantra.:

> **KAli-- Krishna TArA-- RAma Bhuvaneswari-- VarAha Bhairavi-- Nrisimha DhumAvati-- VAmana Chinnamsta-- ParashurAma KamalA-- Matsya BagalAmukhi-- Kurma MAtangi-- Buddha Shodashi-- Kalki.**

Shrimad Dēvī Bhāgavataṃ Book 7 chapter .:on the glory of Śatākṣī.:

> **At this moment, came, out of the body of the Devī, the principal Śaktis (forces incarnate) Kālikā, Tāriṇī, Ṣoḍaśī, Tripurā, Bhairabī, Kamalā, Bagalā, Mātaṅgī, Tripurā Sundarī, Kāmāksī, Tulajā Devī, Jambhinī, Mohinī, Ccinnamaṣtā, and ten thousand armed Guhya Kālīs and others. Thirty-two Śaktis, sixty-four Śaktis, and then innumerable Śaktis, all armed, came out of the Devī successively.**

So, according to Devi Bhagavatam, all Mahavidyas and more came out from Mata Durga during her fight with Durgamasura.

So, the concept is same as the 11 Rudras also have the same names such as Shiva, Shankara, Sthanu, etc and again those names are also applied to Bhagawan Kala Agni Rudra and So on. From whom the 11 Rudras originated.

Conclusion.: Thus, the above mentioned Mata Bhubaneswari is not the part of Dasha Mahavidyas but She is the originator of the 10 Mahavidyas and at the same time all the names can be applied to het also and she can be called by any names such as Tripura Sundari, Maha Kaki, Durga, Sati, Parvati, Bhuvaneshwari, etc etc. Basically, she is the Adi Para Shakti and Maha Vidyas are her partial incarnations.

Sri Shiva Purana 3.16, Dash Avatar (10 Incarnations of Shiva) Describes about the ten incarnations of Shiva and their corresponding power (Shakti).:

> **Sutji said- The first incarnation of lord Shiva was as Mahakal and his Shakti was called Mahakali. Lord Shiva took his second incarnation as Tar and his Shakti was called 'Tara'. The third incarnation of Lord Shiva was as Bhuvaneshwar and his Shakti was called 'Bhuvaneshwari'. Lord Shiva took his fourth incarnation as 'Shodash' who was also known as 'Srividdyesh' and his Shakti was called 'Shodashi' or 'Shri'. Lord Shiva took his fifth incarnation as Bhairav and his Shakti was called 'Bhairavi'. The sixth incarnation of Lord Shiva is famous as 'Chhinamastak' and his Shakti by the name of 'Chhinamasta.Lord Shiva took his seventh incarnation as 'Dhoomvan' and his Shakti was known as 'Dhoomvati. The eighth incarnation was as Baglamukh and his Shakti as Baglamukhi. The nineth incarnation of lord Shiva became famous as Matang and his Shakti as 'Matangi'. Lord Shiva took his tenth incarnation as 'Kamal' and his Shakti as Kamala. If these ten incarnation of Shiva are worshipped along with his ten Mahavidyas then a man attains salvation.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..